# Tomcat needs to be restarted 2 times when uploading new war file

Tags: java, tomcat

When I put a new war file in the webapps directory and restart tomcat, my war file is exploded but the servlets are not available and their respective log files are not created in the logs directory.  When I bounce tomcat again, then the servlets are available and the log files are created.  I'm assuming I have setting(s) not correct within tomcat, but I'm not sure where to start.

Does anyone know the cause of my current situation?  Or even what parameters to review?

New Additional/Comments: Our setup allows us to have our app 'myApp' be the default application that is seen at root of our URL.  On the first starting of tomcat, I can get to myApp by going to /myApp/index.html - whereas on the second start of tomcat I can then just goto  and myApp/index.html is displayed.

My welcome file list is the 'myApp/index.html'

Comment: is there any errors in your tomcat log?
TOMCAT_HOME/logs/

Comment: what is the maven part of this question?

Comment: What happens when you try to put it in the `deploy` directory?

Comment: Please tell whether the context gets started after the first start of tomcat? (You can see it in the manager application)

Comment: Answers to questions:
1. No errors in the logs
2. Version 6.26
3. No real maven question - just FYI for enviroment
4. I'm a newbie at tomcat, is the deploy directory the webapps directory?  I don't deploy when tomcat is running, we shutdown, remove directories/war files from previous version, copy the new war and restart.
5. I have my app as the root of tomcat so I don't have get the welcome page any longer.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Tomcat 6.0.26. I worked around it by deleting the exploded webapps before copying the new war file to the webapps directory. Maybe a little kludgy, but it solved my problem.

Comment: was that while tomcat was still running?

Comment: No, it was part of an ant target that first stops tomcat and then does the above.

Answer (score 0):

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html

```
antiJARLocking
```

If true, the Tomcat classloader will take extra measures to avoid JAR file locking when resources are accessed inside JARs through URLs. This will impact startup time of applications, but could prove to be useful on platforms or configurations where file locking can occur. If not specified, the default value is false.

Answer (score 0):

have you set unpackWars and autoDeploy params to true in your server.xml file?

Comment: ok. I'm not really an expert so I cannot tell you more if I can't see your server.xml file (in the conf directory of Tomcat), which version of Tomcat you use, and your web.xml file (in your application WEB-INF directory). But perhaps it's just a '/' error somewhere... (the logs when tomcat start can be suffisant)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do unpackwars=false and always make sure tomat is not running when you do deployment try to avoid hot deployment...

Comment: I'd like to unpack the war files in case I need to make any changes to the app while its running.